# Tcl/tk: how to set the quality of written jpeg file

Tags: tcl, jpeg, tk-toolkit

Consider this tcl/tk code: it takes PPM-formated RGB data and saves it to a JPG file

```
image create photo tmpImg -data $Data -width $Width -height $Height -format ppm
tmpImg write $FName -format jpeg
image delete tmpImg
```

My question is: how can I set the quality of the resulting JPEG picture?
Is there a "-quality" option in Img::jpeg?
I could not find anything in the sparse documentation available....

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is rather sparse, but these options appear to be supported when reading and writing JPEG images: `-optimize`, `-progressive`, `-quality`, and `-smooth`. The way you pass them when writing an image is more than a bit funky:

```
# Write with 90% quality
tmpImg write $FName -format {jpeg -quality 90}
```

Yes, they're passed *inside* the `-format` option. (Hey, I didn't invent this bizarre hack!)

Comment: Wow, indeed, that's "funky" :) (makes sense though, in the tcl logic). Thanks a lot